# How to properly automount partitions? fstab

Tags: fstab, automounting

I have a problem automounting my NTFS partition I use for storing Data (/dev/sdb2).
I've tried adding an entry to /etc/fstab but it doesn't work.

#### /etc/fstab

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=741be459-4010-4e6f-9ff3-928759f37131 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0e7000d3-12fd-4900-a37e-0705f93fa3ce none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb2        /media/Data    auto    rw,user,auto    0       0
```

I kinda cannot see where is the problem, tried also with the UUID but failed.
OS: CruchBang 11 Waldorf

The reason I don't add it to the ~/.config/openbox/autostart is that it seems
to run after some XDG stuff which I dont know what it is,
so my media directories (music, videos, pictures...), which are links to
/media/Data/, aren't recognized (I think because /dev/sdb2 isn't mounted
at this time).

EDIT:
I've just encountered a weird thing which happens after I've added the
fstab entry:
`Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE`
It happens when I try to mount the drive

Comment: is this auto mount on boot or when drive is inserted?

Comment: No it is a partition on my 2nd hard drive

Comment: so when do you need it to be mounted?

Comment: When booting...

Comment: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged

Comment: try to define the filesystem type in the third column instead of saying `auto`.

Comment: I tried ntfs and ntfs-3g, neither work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a working way!
Here is my line in fstab:
`device_uuid /media/Data ntfs-3g defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0`
Doesn't show it in devices but mounts correctly.
Also the mount folder must exist!

Answer (score 0):

You can mount with the `rc.local` file at boot although that is not the best practice by doing the following in the file,

`mkdir /mnt/mtfs`

`mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ntfs/`